# Navigation bar in UISplitViewController not shown in Supplementary View

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, catalyst

The navigation bar in UISplitViewController is no longer shown in supplementary view since I've updated to Xcode 15, and I do not know how to work around it.

`UINavigationBar.appearance().preferredBehavioralStyle` Is configured to `.pad`.